# WM_MOUSEWHEEL message does not propagate to parent

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a RichTextBox with ScrollBars set to None.  According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> The DefWindowProc function propagates the message to the window's
>   parent. There should be no internal forwarding of the message, since
>   DefWindowProc propagates it up the parent chain until it finds a
>   window that processes it.

I interpret this as, I should not need to hook into the message pump ([IMessageFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter.aspx)) and manually forward WM_MOUSEWHEEL events to the parent Form containing the richtextbox.  When I am inside of RichTextBox and perform a mouse scroll, the Form does not scroll.  Why not?  How can I get the Form to scroll?

Keep in mind that scrollbars are set to none for RichTextBox and enabled for the Form.  So why isn't the form getting the scroll event?

```
public partial class Form4 : Form
{
    public Form4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.AutoScroll = true;
        richTextBox1.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.None;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form doesn't scroll because the RichTextBox handles the WM_MOUSEWHEEL itself and doesn't call `DefWindowProc` to forward it to its parent.  Apparently that doesn't change when disabling the scroll bars.

So you either need to implement an `IMessageFilter` or create a subclass of RichTextEdit that will forward the WM_MOUSEWHEEL as [shown here](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/csharp-programming/115629-disable-richtextbox-mouse-wheel.html):

```
public class NoScrollRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
   const int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A;

   protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
   {
      // This will completely ignore the mouse wheel, which will disable zooming as well
      if (m.Msg != WM_MOUSEWHEEL)
         base.WndProc(ref m);
   }
}
```

Comment: Using this code, once I click inside the RTF I lose all ability to scroll.  Even if I click outside the box I can't scroll anymore.  I think this eats all my messages.  I tried checking for == WM_MOUSEWHEEL instead and got a runtime error.

Comment: Unless something better that works crops up I'm sticking with IMessageFilter.

Answer (score 4):

For my derived TextBox, rather than ignore the mouse wheel as the above does, I instead wanted to pass it on up to my Parent control... which is what the TextBox SHOULD do in any case, in my opinion.  Here's what I put in my derived TextBox's WndProc:

```
switch (m.Msg)
{
    case 0x020A: // WM_MOUSEWHEEL
    case 0x020E: // WM_MOUSEHWHEEL
        if (this.ScrollBars == ScrollBars.None && this.Parent != null)
            m.HWnd = this.Parent.Handle; // forward this to your parent
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        break;

    default:
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        break;
}
```