# How to make multiline TextBox pass MouseWheel events so that container is scrollable

Tags: c#, winforms, events, mouseevent

I have a panel (UserControl) which needs to be mousewheel scrollable. On the panel are a number of multiline textboxes. Even though they do not have scroll bars, they capture the mousewheel events when they have focus. How can I pass the events through to the parent control, so that the panel scrolls with the mousewheel when the multiline textbox is selected?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to use a custom control which inherits from TextBox and overrides the WndProc method. The following solution was adapted from an answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13293422/1453643):

```
class MouseTransparentTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case 0x020A: // WM_MOUSEWHEEL
            case 0x020E: // WM_MOUSEHWHEEL
                if (this.ScrollBars == ScrollBars.None && this.Parent != null)
                    m.HWnd = this.Parent.Handle; // forward this to your parent
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                break;

            default:
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case this didn't work. Overriding WndProc was correct, but I had to re-post the message to the parent control.  `PostMessage(Parent.Handle, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);`

Answer (score 2):

Either `UserControl` or `Textbox` do not show the `MouseWheel` property in the designer. But, you can still wire them. I usually wire them at the class constructor as follows:

```
public partial class CtlCustom: UserControl
{
    public CtlSuggestion()
    {
        this.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(this.UserControl_MouseWheel);
        this.CtlTextbox.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(this.CtlTextBox_MouseWheel);
    }

    private void UserControl_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void CtlTextBox_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

From there to pass `TextBox` mousewheel messages to UserControl, I will just do

```
    private void CtlTextBox_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl_MouseWheel(sender, e);
    }
```

And you will be able to see `Mousewheel` events from the `UserControl` (or `Panel`), and if needed condition the action depending on the `sender` object.

Answer (score 0):

A more straightforward method is to trap the mousewheel event.  On firing, it's easy to move the caret up or down then use ScrollToCaret() to make htat line visible.

```
    private void ScrollTextBox(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        // Mouse wheel has been turned while text box has focus
    {

        // Check scroll amount (+ve is upwards)
        int deltaWheel = e.Delta;
        if (deltaWheel != 0)
        {
            // Find total number of lines
            int nLines = edtAddress.Lines.Length;
            if (nLines > 0)
            {
                // Find line containing caret
                int iLine = edtAddress.GetLineFromCharIndex(edtAddress.SelectionStart);
                if (iLine >= 0)
                {
                    // Scroll down
                    if (deltaWheel > 0)
                    {
                        // Move caret to start of previous line
                        if (iLine > 0)
                        {
                            int position = edtAddress.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(iLine - 1);
                            edtAddress.Select(position, 0);

                        }
                    }
                    else // Scroll up
                    {
                        // Move caret to start of next line
                        if (iLine < (nLines - 1))
                        {
                            int position = edtAddress.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(iLine + 1);
                            edtAddress.Select(position, 0);
                        }
                    }

                    // Scroll to new caret position
                    edtAddress.ScrollToCaret();
                }
            }        

        } 

    }
```